# If Difference Higher or Lower than Display

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need an Excel formula that will show:

- `1` if B is less than A by more than 2
- `0` if B is within 2 of A
- `-1` if B is higher than A by more than 2

Can someone please tell me whether this is possible and point me in the right direction?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a formula / script writing service, so we need you to tell us what you have already attempted and we will help you from there. What formula are you using in the "Formula" column? Have you looked at the [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function yet?

Comment: I have looked at the IF function but there was nothing I could see that included this criteria by default. Without even knowing if this can be done I can re-clarify my question as "is this possible?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
=IF(B1<(A1-2),1,IF(B1>(A1+2),-1,0))
```

The first `IF` checks if `B1` is less than `A1-2`, which means that `B1` is less than `A1` by more than 2. It returns 1 if true, otherwise it checks for the second condition; `IF` `B1` is more than `A1+2`. It returns -1 if true, otherwise 0. Finally you close both `IF` functions.

Comment: This one is probably faster, fewer IF's to process.

Comment: Thanks, had to fluff around with it but this definitely put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, here is one of the ways that it can be done:

- `=IF(ABS(A1-B1)>2,IF(A1>B1,1,IF(A1<B1,-1)),0)`

The first part of the formula checks to see if there is a difference of more than 2, if so it will then check to see if A is larger than B (1) or if B is larger than A (-1), finally it will give the result if the difference between A and B is less than 2 (0).

Comment: You checked to see whether the difference was more than 2, if yes checked for A>B, then if no checked is A<B.  The final check is uneccessary - once you know that one is at least two more than the other, then if A is no bigger than B it MUST be smaller.  In other words, `IF(ABS(A1-B1)>2,IF(A1>B1,1, -1),0)`